# How do I print each character one by one?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, char, header-files

I'm trying to print the characters in this array one by one in a table with 7 rows and 4 columns. However, the only output I get is the whole alphabet in every column and row. How do I print each character one by one in the order I want?
Note that the table is supposed to end with a space and a `.`.

The output should look like this:

```
a b c d
e f g h
h i j k
l m n o
p q r s
t u v w
y z   .
```

This is my code:

```
struct pagestruct sequence[ROWS];
char alfabet[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz .";

for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
  printf("\n");
  for (int k = 0; k < COLUMNS; k++) {
    strcpy(sequence[k].page, alfabet);
    printf("%s", sequence[k].page);
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

This is the header file:

```
#define COLUMNS 4
#define ROWS 7 

struct pagestruct
{
  char page[COLUMNS];
};
```

Comment: What is `pagestruct`? By providing that, you will be providing an minimal example. ;)

Comment: I would write a loop running `i` from 0 to 25.  Each trip through the loop, I would print `alfabat[i]` followed by a space.  Then, if `i` was a multiple of 4, I'd print a `\n`.  For extra credit, I'd arrange not to print the space just before the `\n`.

Comment: This really shows no understanding whatsoever of programming in any language.

Comment: well... ok, more about fortunetelling than C then :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you have the function. If the string is terminated by the `" ."` it takes the data up to `'.'`. If not it takes the data up to number of rows and columns or the end of the string to avoid an UB. If the string is too short the rest of the table is filled with spaces. Of course you can break at this point but i do not know if it is the idea.

Because you wanted to fill another table I did it the same way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIDANTAL    7
#define BYTE 4

int main(void)
{
    char alfabet[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz .";
    char sequence[SIDANTAL][BYTE * 2 + 1];
    char *end = strstr(alfabet, " .");
    size_t len = end ? (end - alfabet + 2) : strlen(alfabet), cpos = 0;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < SIDANTAL; i++)
    {
        for(size_t k = 0; k < BYTE; k++)
        {
            sequence[i][k * 2] = cpos < len ? alfabet[cpos] : ' ';
            sequence[i][k * 2 + 1] = ' ';
            cpos++;
        }
        sequence[i][BYTE * 2] = 0;
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < SIDANTAL; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", sequence[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I must say I feel like you answered another question... where did you see sequence array type in the original question?

Comment: @OznOg my friend - there is no declaration of the struct so I cant use it. And my answer answers the question 100% Please do not `T`

Comment: `struct pagestruct` probably is something like `struct pagestruct { char page[BYTE]; };` - probably, it's a guess.

Comment: @Rabbid76 definitely not `char page[BYTE]`